# In Python, why is 'r+' but not 'rw' used to mean "read & write"?

Tags: python

In Python, when opening a file, we use `'r'` to indicate read-only and `'w'` write-only. Then we use `'r+'` to mean "read and write".

Why not use `'rw'`? Doesn't `'rw'` looks more natural than `'r+'`?

---

Edit on Jan. 25th:

Oh.. I guess my question looks a little confusing.. What I was trying to ask is: `'r'` is the first letter of 'read' and `'w'` the first letter of 'write' so `'r'` and `'w'` look natural to map to 'read' and 'write'. However, when it comes to 'read and write', Python uses 'r+' instead of `'rw'`.

So the question is actually about the naming rationale instead of the behavior differences between them.

Comment: Note that `r+`, `w+` and `a+` all mean "read and write" but they have subtleties. `r+` doesn't create a file, `w+` does, `a+` appends to the file and creates if it doesn't exist. A catch-all `rw` would be ambiguous in that regard. `wr` would not read as cleanly, and `aw` or `ar` is just weird.

Comment: Rapptz's explanation is wrong.  'rw' and 'wr' have obvious semantics, as does 'ar' ('aw' would be redundant).  The plus versions (r+, w+, a+) are completely unintuitive and break backward compatibliity with python 2, where 'rw' works as intended.  'r+' is just another bad design from python3.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Python copies the modes from [C's `fopen()` call](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen). `r+` is what C uses, and Python stuck with the 40-year-old convention.

Comment: Note that there is also w+ and a+. They could be named wr and ar, but I think someone thought r+, w+, and a+ was somehow better. It's not like you can just combine them arbitrarily and still have it making sense. For example, aw wouldn't make sense. So having a different name for each mode makes more sense than allowing for combining modes.

Comment: `r+`,  `w+`, and `a+` do three different things, and -- `fopen` being one of the *really old* C library interfaces -- the original implementation probably did something nonsensical if you passed `rw`, so C89 just forbade you to do that.  The POSIX `open` function with its three-way choice `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, `O_RDWR`, and then a bunch of modifiers has always struck me as a more ergonomic design.

Comment: So the question becomes: "In C, why is 'r+' but not 'rw' used to mean “read & write”?"

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida : I like your answer the most, and, after reading it, I agree with your point. Yes, if we had 'rw' for 'read & write', novice programmers may take it as a 'combination game' so they start combining things that don't make sense which cause frustration to them and bugs to users. Having different names increase the learning burden a tiny little bit but could save a lot of effort. In general, it is cost-effective.

Comment: @Kynit: That's a funny trend of how this question goes and I didn't expect that... Obviously I need to learn more of how to ask a clear question, and they should learn how to interpret a question.. ;-)

Comment: @rob: That's fair — better 'r+' than 'rw' — but it would have been better to design it as zwol describes.

Comment: 'rw' is not only better but python2 accepted 'rw'.  Only python3 reverted back to broken C behavior.  Why break something that's already fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens:

```py
>>> f1 = open("blabla.txt", 'rw');
Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:18:40) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> f1=open("blabla.txt",'rw')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    f1=open("blabla.text",'rw')
ValueError: must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode
```

It's just how the read/write/append function is configured in core python. Some will say that it has to do with old c-style fopen() directives `r` `w` `r+` etc.

Comment: @immibis Arguably, so is "it's `rw` because that's what C did".

Comment: i suppose another argument is "Python foundation simply didn't want to have it in a different way"?

Answer (score 0):

Don't took it as pure English, `r+`  means `read extended` actually, `Python!=English.` All of the languages has basic rules, and @John Kugelman mentioned, Python stuck with old.

Comment: @WChargin Depends, you might not want to do that if both `Python` and `English` are variables because you're doing a id comparison.

Comment: @ıɯɐƃoʇǝızuǝʞ True. However, some languages (at least C and Java) use `==` exclusively for id/reference equality. C++ and C# and others allow you to overload `==` for value equality, though. So either seems feasible to me.